# PubsubIO.Read guidance on Windowing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io) (docs are 1.x, although I'm using 2.2):

> Note: By default, PubsubIO transforms create unbounded PCollections. After you create a PCollection by using PubsubIO.Read, you should apply a windowing strategy to that PCollection before applying any transforms that group elements, such as GroupByKey or Combine.

1. So if I don't need to use a grouping transform, is there no need to apply a window when using PubsubIO.Read?
2. If I do use a grouping transform, but haven't specified a window, what happens? Is there a default window applied by default from PubsubIO.Read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default windowing strategy is to use a single global window which all elements belong to.

If you're certain that your pipeline doesn't use an grouping or aggregation, then you can use the default global windows. However, you will likely still need a [trigger](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers) condition to specify at what point data should be written from a sink transform. Otherwise, data will accumulate in the global window forever, causing your pipeline to appear stuck.

The Beam documentation has additional details about windowing here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

Comment: My understanding is there is no need for windowing or triggering if the pipeline is not performing any group-by operations on the data in the single global window.

Comment: @scott-wegner is the accumulating data in the global window because the [default trigger emits exactly once](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#event-time-triggers)? If it does only emit once, when does that actually happen?

Comment: Default trigger emits after 'watermark' passes end of the window. If you have 1 minute fixed windows, window for 9:05-9:06 fires when 'watermark' for the input goes past 9:06. For default global window, end time is infinity. So it won't fire at all (in the case of Dataflow it will fire when you 'drain' a pipeline, but that is not relevant here I think). A streaming pipeline with aggregations does require windowing.. otherwise the pipeline does not know how long to keep on aggregating.

Comment: So what would happen if I have a pipeline entirely of ParDos (no PDone sinks, say it's a custom ParDo that manually saves to DataStore or something), reading from an unbounded source (PubSub)? Would I still need triggers/windows at all?

Comment: Not required. These are single stage pipelines. Windows are required only if you an aggregation (some variant of GroupByKey, either directly or indirectly).